# Can Resque Cleaner be expanded to store >1000 failed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have Resque Cleaner set up with Redis and a Ruby on Rails framework. I noticed the cleaner fills with failed jobs up until the 1000 mark. I've been trying to find a way to increase the 1000 threshold with no luck yet, is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is covered in the readme here: https://github.com/ono/resque-cleaner

Add this to a resque-web config file:

```
# [app_dir]/config/resque-web.rb
require 'resque-cleaner'
module Resque::Plugins
  ResqueCleaner::Limiter.default_maximum = 10_000
end
```

Then pass the file when you start resque-web

```
$ resque-web [app_dir]/config/resque-web.rb
```